# Does IBM MobileFirst 7.0.0 be used to build for Windows Phone 10 devices?

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-8, visual-studio-2013, ibm-mobilefirst, windows-10

I have a windows live store application which was built in **IBM MF 7.0.**

- This application was built in eclipse selecting **WindowsPhone8** environment
- Extracted **.csProject** to **Visual Studio 2013 update 4**
- Re-targeted to **Windows Phone Silverlight 8.1**
- Submitted to the store

Application is working fine as expected in Windows phone 8.1 and tried to install it in Windows Phone 10 device but here the application shows splash screen for a while and then goes black/blank.

Tried to re-target to windows 10 but I don't see any options in VS 2013.
As per the Link https://canbilgin.wordpress.com/2015/04/03/retarget-projects-to-windows-10/  Visual Studio 2015 Extension to upgrade the existing Windows Store 8.1 or Windows Phone 8.1 (not Silverlight) projects to Windows 10 UAP applications.

But my application is Windows Phone 8.1 Silverlight, Whether IBM MobileFirst supports WP Silverlight 8.1 to be targeted for windows 10 environment?

Please suggest in proceeding further

Comment: MobileFirst apps retargeted to Windows Phone 8.1 should work on Windows 10 as well. Can you mention if this is a hybrid or a native Windows Phone app. Also, can you upload the app project to dropbox or some file sharing platform and provide the link

Comment: This is a hybrid application. Sorry that I couldn't disclose the project here I just created a sample project which I am sharing here please follow the [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/o75q9irx20yd5x2/sample.zip?dl=0)

Answer (score 0):

Windows Phone 8.1 silverlight app that is re-targeted to Windows Phone 10 and compiled with Visual Studio 2013 or 2015 should work OK. This is a scenario that was tested.

If you are using a framework that may interfere with the build process then I suggest to open a PMR to have the specific scenario further investigated.